# MQTT qos 2 timeout between PUBREC and PUBREL

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, qos

Is there some timeout mechanism for MQTT between PUBREC and PUBREL in QOS 2?

Or the timeout is same as global keep alive timeout?

Thanks!

[image: Diagram from HiveMQ]
Diagram from HiveMQ (http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-6-mqtt-quality-of-service-levels)

Comment: Have you looked at the spec?

Comment: Hi @hardillb, I've read seldom timeout about the time between qos1 or 2. Almost every "timeout" wording is for keep alive timeout. This retry section (http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/webservices/ws-mqtt/mqtt-v3r1.html#retry) said that the timeout is configurable, but I don't know where is the config in mosquitto.

Comment: I've got some problem about mosquitto server and a non-open sourced chip, the mqtt library may broke on some situation, so I'm tracing what may happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mosquitto the option you are looking for is

`retry_interval`

Taken from the [man](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) page

> retry_interval seconds
>
> The integer number of seconds after a QoS=1 or QoS=2 message has been
>   sent that mosquitto will wait before retrying when no response is
>   received. If unset, defaults to 20 seconds.
>
> Reloaded on reload signal.

Comment: Thanks! I search timeout and missed it!